# How do you get the fully qualified class name in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, eclipse-plugin

Is there a fast way to click on a Java class in Eclipse and obtain its fully qualified name, or copy it to the clipboard?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

1. Hover the mouse pointer over the name of a class in the editor window, it can be anywhere in the code where a class name appears
2. In the pop-up window that appears, double-click the fully-qualified name
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to copy

Alternatively:

1. In the project explorer (generally the left window), click on a class name
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to display the properties window
3. Select and copy the class' path. But you'll need to manually replace the `/` characters with `.`

Answer (score 21):

Edit on 2016-06-29:

**As pointed by Jeff, you only need the 2nd step in the following：**

<del>1. Double-click on the class name in the source code.</del>
2. Right-click and select "Copy Qualified Name"

[image]

Comment: if anyone gets a `file path` instead of the `fully qualified name` -> make sure you double click to `select the whole class name` before `right click`.

Answer (score 7):

When you hover over it, you see the full name.

[image]

And if you click on the window that opens, you can mark the full name and copy it to the clipboard :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clicking the "Fully Qualified Name" item in the popup, you can simply use its shortcut, `Y`, when menu is shown. See letter Y underlined on screenshot in Dollyn's answer.

Comment: As seen in Dollyn's answer, in step 2 you can use the underlined shortcut letter 'y', instead of moving your mouse to the last item and select. Even step 1 is not needed btw.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simpler solution: just create a key shortcut

Menu Window > Preferences > (write "keys") > search for "Copy Qualified Name" > add any not-yet-assigned key shortcut. Apply > OK.

There. Ready to use. Easy.