# How to get the full class name of the of an Java file in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, classname

Often I would like to copy the fully qualified class name of the class the is open in the Java file editor in Eclipse.

There is a similar question: [How do you get the fully qualified class name in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597424) but all the answers only work for classes you use in your source code but not for the Java class file currently open in the editor.

There is also an menu entry called "Copy qualified Name" in the context menu of the file element shown in the `Package Explorer` view, but if you execute this you only get the path name within the current project and not the class name.

How can I get the fully qualified class name separated with dots for an arbitrary Java file in a project or for an Java file that is currently open. For example if I have the file `src/min/java/com/example/MyClass.java` open in the Java editor how can I get directly the class name `com.exmaple.MyClass`?

Comment: A Java file can contain more than one class. So you have to select the class (in the _Package Explorer_ and _Project Explorer_ first sub-node of the Java file and in the _Outline_ view the root element; in the breadcrumb right of the package), not the Java file which is a different thing.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much what the previous answer said. I however have shortcuts to do that.

1. I bound the shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+S` to focus/show the current file in the Package Explorer
2. You can then right-click the class in the Package Explorer treeview to select "Copy Qualified Name", or if you use that often, bind a shortcut to it (eg: `Ctrl+Shift+C`). It is listed in the available commands of the Keys dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the class in the *Outline* view and right click the mouse. In the context menu, there is menu item **Copy Qualified Name**

[image: Eclipse Outline view context menu screen capture]

I am using Eclipse 2021-03

[image: About Eclipse]

You can also right click on any class name in the editor window. **Copy Qualified Name** appears in the context menu.

[image: Eclipse editor context menu]